# Conflict resolution using SwiftUI FileDocument?

Tags: swiftui

Using the new SwiftUI support for FileDocument, is there a way to provide conflict resolution like there is for UIDocument? UIDocument provides `documentState` and `stateChangedNotification`. There is nothing defined in the FileDocument that indicates this capability. And SwiftUI does not seem to provide any automatic conflict resolution UI for your app. So when the user selects a document with conflicting versions, your app is unaware and simply opens the document for the user to edit.

Comment: My suggestion is to stick with UIDocument for now. I tried to reimplement something that I have already implemented in UIKit in SwiftUI, but got very frustrated, and now I think I am going to just wait it out.

Comment: Agreed, I’m staying with UIDocument for now. I’ve filed a feature request with Apple, but have gotten no response.

Comment: I gave feedback requesting that `UIDocument` is given a conflict resolution UI like `NSDocument` has on macOS, please reference FB12495930 in yours. Once that is implemented my home is SwiftUI conflict resolution will "just work".